# which one is better in installing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I followed the instructions on the official website to download the TensorFlow. I chose to create a virtual environment as the instruction shown for macOS. My question is that if I need to activate the virtual environment each time before I use TensorFlow?

For example, I want to use tensor flow on Jupiter notebook and that means I need to install Jupiter and other required packages like Seaborn/pandas as well on the virtual environment. However I already downloaded anaconda and basically, it has all the packages I need.

Besides, will it make a difference if I download it with conda?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you downloaded the packages (like you said TensorFlow and Seaborn) in the **base Conda environment** which is the default environment that anaconda provides on installation, then to use what it has, you need to run whatever program/IDE like Jupyter lab from it. So you would open Anaconda Prompt and then type in `jupyter lab` and it would open up a new socket and you can edit with your installed python libraries from Conda.
Otherwise in IDE's VSCode you can simply set the python interpreter to that from Conda.

However, if you install the libraries and packages you need using pip on your actual python installation not Conda, then there is no need for any activation. Everything will run right out of the box. You don't need to select the interpreter in IDE's like VSCode.

Bottom line, if you know what libraries you need and don't mind running `pip install package-name` every time you need a package, stick with pip.
If you don't like to that sort of 'low level' stuff then use Anaconda or Miniconda.